# Join two sys.columns tables from different servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two similar dbs on two different servers. I'm trying to join their `sys.columns` tables, but I don't understand why this wouldn't work

```
SELECT *
             FROM server1.db1.sys.columns t
             INNER JOIN server2.db2.sys.columns s
             ON        OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id]) = OBJECT_NAME(s.[object_id])
             AND       t.name        = s.name 
             WHERE     OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id]) = 'commonTable'
```

`commonTable` exists in both dbs. Above query returns empty set

I join on `OBJECT_NAME` because their `object_id`s obviously different, since they are located on different dbs, so I join on their names in that way

Comment: Why are you using `object_name()`?  Why not just use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`?

Comment: Because their object_id s obviously different, cuz they are located on different dbs. I need sys.columns, and not iNFORMATION_SHEMA.COLUMNS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OBJECT_NAME()` works *locally* so it is never going to return the name of some object id in another database. Join to the foreign sys.columns *and* sys.objects view.

```
SELECT *
  FROM server1.db1.sys.columns AS loc_c
  INNER JOIN server2.db2.sys.columns AS rem_c
  ON loc_c.name = rem_c.name
  INNER JOIN server1.db1.sys.tables AS loc_t
  ON loc_t.[object_id] = loc_c.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN server2.db2.sys.tables AS rem_t
  ON loc_t.name = rem_t.name
  AND rem_t.[object_id] = rem_c.[object_id]
  WHERE loc_t.name = N'commonTable';
```

You may want to add local and remote joins to `sys.schemas`, too, since `dbo.foo` and `otherschema.foo` will both match.

You may also consider synonyms and/or views to reduce complexity, if you are doing this a lot.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.server1cols
AS 
  SELECT [table] = loc_t.name, [column] = loc_c.name
    FROM server1.db1.sys.columns AS loc_c
     INNER JOIN server1.db1.sys.tables AS loc_t
     ON loc_t.[object_id] = loc_c.[object_id];
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.server2cols
AS 
  SELECT [table] = rem_t.name, [column] = rem_c.name
    FROM server2.db2.sys.columns AS rem_c
     INNER JOIN server2.db2.sys.tables AS rem_t
     ON rem_t.[object_id] = rem_c.[object_id];
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.MatchDB1DB2Cols
AS
  SELECT s1.[table],
         db1column = s1.[column],
         db2column = s2.[column]
  FROM dbo.server1cols AS s1
  INNER JOIN dbo.server2cols AS s2
  ON s1.[table] = s2.[table]
  AND s1.[column] = s2.[column];
GO
```

Now your query is simply:

```
SELECT [table], db1column, db2column
  FROM dbo.MatchDB1DB2Cols
  WHERE [table] = N'commonTable';
```

You may also want to consider a full outer join somewhere so you can also note *differences* between the tables.